# How to show magento rules based product from related product rule programmatically

Tags: magento2.3

Currently crosssell product is showing based on product level.  I need to get the collection of crossell based on magento related product rules . Kindly help me

Answer (score 0):

Get List Products from Catalog Rule Condition in Magento 2:

```
$productCollection = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(
         '\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection'
     );
     $productFactory = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(
         '\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory'
     );
     $this->_productIds = [];
     $this->setCollectedAttributes([]);
     $this->getConditions()->collectValidatedAttributes($productCollection);
     \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(
         '\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Iterator'
     )->walk(
         $this->_productCollection->getSelect(),
         [[$this, 'callbackValidateProduct']],
         [
             'attributes' => $this->getCollectedAttributes(),
             'product' => $productFactory->create()
         ]
     );
```